# Difference between SIFT and Hue-SIFT point descriptor technique

Tags: image, image-processing

What is the difference between SIFT and Hue-SIFT algorithm in point descriptor of an image?

Answer (score 0):

HUE SIFT As the name specifies it is connected with incorporating color information in the SIFT feature extraction process.
One of the most distinguishable properties of this descriptor is the ability to map skin color shades for person classification necessities. So, The length of (descriptor) extracted feature vectors is longer (165) because of the color information that is incorporated.